# Scaling AppEngine applications

Tags: google-app-engine

I've been thinking lately about the pros and cons of using AppEngine.

My concern would be, when we create application for GAE, the front-end code (the UI stuff) is served from the same application instance in the GAE cloud as with the Datastore codes.

The question would be when my applications grows:

For GAE:

- Do I need to create multiple instance of my application?
- If so, what do I need to manually update all instances?

For [Appscale](http://code.google.com/p/appscale/):

- Do I also need to create multiple instance of my application?
- If so, what do I need to manually update all instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GAE starts new frontend instances automatically, you even can't create or update frontend instances. You just need to configure min/max latency, min/max idle instances in Application Settings. See [docs for performance settings](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings)

Btw, there are also [Backend Instances](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview) that can be Resident and started manually from Admin Console. But it's useful only when you need something very specific

Comment: When you say "can't create or update frontent instances" you mean that my application is essentially just one GAE instance, I mean like myapp.appspot.com, where I do not have to worry about creating new GAE instance, when the capacity for the current application instance is too high and needs to scale?

Comment: myapp.appspot.com is a application `myapp`, gae automatically starts new instances (say jetty instance with your code), depends on load. Each moment there can be different number of instances - 5 minutes ago it was '1 instance', now it's '3 intance', 5 minutes later it can be '2 instances'. Each instance can be started and killed at any moment, etc

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have missed the whole point of AppEngine, which is that Google takes care of scaling your app for you automatically. You seem to be confusing 'instance' with 'version' - you have control over which version of your app is serving, but Google dynamically creates and kills instances of that app depending on load. That's the main benefit of using AppEngine in the first place.

Comment: Yah, I got confused at some point here, mainly because I am thinking of "Front-End" and "Back-end" part of my application, usually when doing traditional apps, we tend to think this way, the front-end (usually served from a Tomcat server) and the back-end which can be a separate server that mainly host database and db-logic